# Angular 2 EventEmitter calls for all not nested components

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I have 2 components with one same nested component in each.
Nested component has EventEmitter which trigger method of parent component

```
<parent1>
    <nested (changed)="onChanged1($event)"></nested>
</parent2>
<parent2>
    <nested (changed)="onChanged2($event)"></nested>
</parent2>
```

onChanged1 and onChanged2 call after every 'changed' emit.

in onChanged2 i have event data from 'changed' eventEmitter from parent1!

Please give an advice how to avoid this problem

Comment: create 2 event emitter's (changed1)="onChanged1($event)" & (changed2)="onChanged2($event)" in nested component

Comment: @Sam in this case we lost main independence of nested component

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: @Output decorator is to communicate from a child to parent component i:e is to pass data from child to parent or to any other component through out the application.

Comment: @Input decorator is to communicate from parent to child component i:e to pass data from parent to child component.

Comment: if you want to pass data from parent to a child component you can use @Input decorator. There no need to emit or produce an event for that. Possibly if you can show your code that would be helpful